# initialize client socket in node file that will be sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, websocket, socket.io

I send information to clients from a nodejs server like this :

```js
app.get([...]
    let index = await readFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'file.js'), 'utf8');
    res.send(index);
)
```

I want to initialise a socket in my file.js.

In the socket io documentation, you can do this:

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

So I try to copy/paste `socket.io.js` directly in my `file.js` and add `var socket = io();` at the end, but I got this error on my client : `GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NXz6N1S 404 (Not Found)`

There is a way to initialize my client socket in the file.js?

EDIT:

my server.js file:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');

[...]

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
  });

[...]

app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    let index = await readFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'file.js'), 'utf8');
    res.send(index);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`ok = ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It works! You have successfully moved `socket.io.js` into your own JS file and told it to connect at the end.

However, the *connection attempt* fails, because nothing is listening on the path that the socket.io back-end uses. The most likely reason is that you're missing [the part of code that integrates socket.io with the back-end HTTP server](https://socket.io/get-started/chat#Integrating-Socket-IO):

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Without this, socket.io cannot establish a connection because the server is not accepting the client's requests. Enable server-side handling and the whole thing should start working.

Do note, however, that this is most likely not a good idea in the long run - the standard way, suggested by socket.io docs, is to use the bundled `socket.io.js` file that the server exposes under `GET /socket.io/socket.io.js` by default, because this is the easiest way to make sure the code version is compatible. If you just copy the source of `socket.io-client` into your own file, and then in some time (a few months) somebody decides to update the server-side Socket.io version, the application may break because the client is not updated.

Comment: I already have these lines in my server : `const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);`

Comment: @SamuelRodriguez-Lozano And http://127.0.0.1:5500 is the back-end?

Comment: No, my server run on the port 8000 !

Comment: The 5500 port is the vscode server use for my index.html client test, which call `<script src="http://localhost:8000/[...]"></script>` inside it

Comment: @SamuelRodriguez-Lozano There you go - you'll need to point the client at the server; it doesn't know that it should use :8000 by itself. Even though you're loading the script from :8000, socket.io does not know where it's loaded from because it executes in the global context of the browser window. See: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/ - specify your back-end here.